# SQL JOIN get name and all tags for item

Tags: php, mysql, join

this is my first ever JOIN clause and I did run into a problem. I want to echo all the necessary information for my items but I don't understand how to echo all the tags for one item, right now I get a list with duplicates of items but with different tags if more than one tag is assigned for an item. Any ideas? Better ways to do this is greatly appreciated as well.

```
$query = "SELECT categories.id, categories.category, spots.spot_name, spots.category_id, spots.description, spots.slug, districts.id, districts.district, tags.spot_id, tags.tag ".
 "FROM categories, spots, districts, tags ".
    "WHERE categories.id = spots.category_id AND districts.id = spots.district_id AND tags.spot_id = spots.id";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<tr><td style="background:#000; color:#ccc;" class="tooltip" title="'.$row["description"].'Tags: '.$row["tag"].'"><a style="color:#fff;" href="/'.$row["slug"].'">'.$row["spot_name"].'</a></td>
<td>'.$row["category"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["district"].'</td>
<td>****</td>
</tr>  
';
}
```

Thanks a million,

Anders

Answer (score 0):

Change your Query and add left join like this:

$query= "SELECT c.id, c.category, s.spot_name, s.category_id, s.description,".
        " s.slug, d.id, d.district, t.spot_id, t.tag".
        " FROM categories AS c, spots AS s, districts AS d".
        " JOIN tags AS t ON s.id = t.spot_id".
        " WHERE c.id = s.category_id AND d.id = s.district_id";

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, but that gives me the exact same outcome as my code. Any suggestion of how I can get all the tags echoed for one item and not have duplicate items (spots) echoed in my table?

Comment: Oh! sorry! yes you are right. there is a simple solution. you can merge records of the same id in PHP :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how your query looks much better to read:

```
SELECT c.id, c.category, s.spot_name, s.category_id, s.description, s.slug, d.id, d.district, t.spot_id, t.tag 
  FROM spots AS s
  LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = s.category_id
  LEFT JOIN districts AS d ON d.id = s.district_id
  LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON t.spot_id = s.id
```

To get all spots you like to issue this query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.category, s.spot_name, s.category_id, s.description, s.slug, d.id, d.district
  FROM spots AS s
  LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = s.category_id
  LEFT JOIN districts AS d ON d.id = s.district_id
```

Now you can loop over all the spots and get their tags:

```
'SELECT t.tag FROM tags WHERE t.spot_id = '. (int)$spot_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you mean with the loop in the last step? Do you mean a normal PHP while loop with a new SQL query every time? Wouldnt that slow everything down?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. 2 queries are slower, but I think it is the only way if you want to prevent duplicate items. Cause when you join all in one table and an item has multiple tags it will occure as many times as there are items.